# XML String transform

Tags: java, xml, string, dom

I have following XML string:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>Someone</name>
        <age>27</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Otherone</name>
        <age>43</age>
    </person>
</persons>
```

I want to take this string and to get from it a DOM object. It could be any XML string (not from file!).

*Sorry for this newbie question,Thanks a lot for helpers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc =
  javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(
        ).parse(
   new org.xml.sax.InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xmlString)));
```

Comment: Thanks,It returns an exception if the xml string is not well formated,How I can work with non-well formated xml strings?

Comment: @Yosi You can catch the exception and report the error. If you want to fetch data from a string which may or may not contain well-formed XML you might want use regular expressions.

Comment: @Yosi another approach: use SAX parser and handle tags/attrs/characters until the parser hasn't met the error. Maybe you can explain what you want to do?

Comment: Hi,I am sorry ,it works very well with unformated xml string .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;



public class String2XML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {
        String xml="<persons><person><name>Someone</name><age>27</age></person><person><name>Otherone</name><age>43</age></person></persons>";
        DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
        parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xml))); 
        Document doc = parser.getDocument();
        System.out.println("String2XML.main()-"+doc.toString());
    }
}
```

Dont forget including xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar in your classpath. You can find them here http://archive.apache.org/dist/xml/xerces-j/binaries/